# Failed to compile, bootstrap on webpack

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to integrate js,css and html with webpack for the front end part of my application. I tried with customised css in **application.css** file and then imported that in **application.js**. It was working.

Now I removed the css code and installed bootstrap using **yarn**.

Following is my **package.json**

```
"name": "evil_chat",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^3.2.0",
    "coffeescript": "1.12.7",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7"
```

Once I ran `yarn install` the bootstrap package was installed in the **node_modules** directory. Then I tried to import **bootstrap.css** from bootstrap directory into **application.js** file by doing the following.

**application.css**

```
@import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

**application.js**

```
import "./application.css";

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "afterbegin",
  "Finally webpacker!!!"
);
console.log("Hello World from Webpacker");
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Failed to compile.

./frontend/packs/application.css
Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot' in '/home/desmond/Projects/React/evil_chat/frontend/packs'
```

But I didn't get this error when I imported `@import "normalize.css/normalize.css";`. I am getting this only with bootstrap. What am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `bootstrap.css` have dependency on `glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot` which may not be present in your application. Download this files and keep them in relevant folder structure. Maintain the folder structure accordingly.

Else in `bootstrap.css` files search by that font name and comment that code

Comment: I was trying to fix this for many time, at last found that `glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot` which may not be present in my application's font folder.